# testrpc --account private key length is invalid even though its my account

Tags: contract-deployment, testrpc, nodejs

I tried to initiate a testrpc account and passing my account with value to test the transactions but when I keyed in my key `0x94fd019eeb92780477b01ce5555513d3755b5193` it says that the key is invalid.

Why is it invalid even though its my key?

EDIT: full log of error down below

> C:\Users\user>testrpc --account="0x94fd019eeb92780477b01ce5555513d3755b5193,1000"
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:74143
>   var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]){if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WEB"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="WORKER"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="NODE"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=true}else if(Module["ENVIRONMENT"]==="SHELL"){ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=true}else{throw new Error("The provided Module['ENVIRONMENT'] value is not valid. It must be one of: WEB|WORKER|NODE|SHELL.")}}else{ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&"function"==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WOR
>
> RangeError: private key length is invalid
>       at Object.exports.isBufferLength (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:60654:39)
>       at Object.publicKeyCreate (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:60446:14)
>       at Object.exports.privateToPublic (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:7065:20)
>       at StateManager.createAccount (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:90434:25)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at StateManager.initialize (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:90342:33)
>       at new GethApiDouble (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:89816:14)
>       at new Provider (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:28446:23)
>       at Object.create (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:105938:20)
>       at Object.server (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:59272:19)

Comment: Can you provide the full error and the steps to reproduce it please?

Comment: @Andromelus I typed in testrpc --account="0x94fd019eeb92780477b01ce5555513d3755b5193,1000" but it gave me invalid key

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try dropping the quotes? I helped with an issue earlier relating to that, though frankly I don't think it's likely to be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a private key here, which is `0x` + 64 hex characters.

`0x94fd019eeb92780477b01ce5555513d3755b5193` is only 40 hex characters and looks like an account address rather than a private key.

If you have the private key for this account, then try that. Depending on how you generated the account, you may not have easy access to the private key. If you have a UTC style key file, then you can use MyEtherWallet's View Wallet Info facility to see it.

Comment: I tried that as well but it was invalid, I have another testrpc running while doing this though, is that the reason why?